# Get List of files from directory in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a directory `"/local/dath/mi/"` which is including many files

```
03_ssa_fruits.csv
03_ssa_can.csv
03_ssa_veg.csv
sxattru.csv
sxprod.csv
sxstore.csv
```

I need to extract the list of specific files from that directory :

```
/local/dath/mi/03_ssa_fruits.csv
/local/dath/mi/03_ssa_can.csv
/local/dath/mi/03_ssa_veg.csv
```

I have tried the below code ,but it is not working.What I am doing wrong .Can anyone help me

```
def getListOfFiles(dir: String , naming: String): List[String] = {
      File(dir).toJava.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList.filter { file =>
        file.getName.startsWith("03_ss*")
      }.map(_.toString)
    }


   val listOfFile = getListOfFiles(parentDir, File(data.salFilePath).toJava.getName())
```

Comment: Try to remove `*` in file.getName.startsWith("03_ss*")

Comment: look into documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-
String object method `startsWith ` has no support of regexp including wildcard so you need to specify just prefix `03_ss`

Comment: thanks ,it is working now.My mistake.Apologies !!

Comment: [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) is the best modern solution for performing filesystem operations like this with Scala.  os-lib makes listing files so much easier and hides all the complexity of the underlying Java libs.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a simple example

```
import java.io.File

def getListOfFiles(dir: String): List[String] = {
  val file = new File(dir)
  file.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)
    .filter(_.getName.startsWith("03_ss"))
    .map(_.getPath).toList
}
getListOfFiles("dirrectory path")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) is the easiest, most elegant way to perform Scala filesystem operations.

Here's how to list the files that start with "03_ss":

```scala
os.list(os.pwd/"local_data").filter(_.segments.toList.last.startsWith("03_ssa"))
```

This solution is powerful because it lets you perform additional filesystem operations on the files that start with "03_ssa".  You can move these files to an other directory, get the file sizes, rename them, delete them, whatever you want.

It's not like the other solutions that simply returns a list of strings.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/) for more info on how to harness the power of os-lib.

Here's the code snippet to setup a folder with OP's files if you'd like to experiment on your own machine:

```scala
os.makeDir(os.pwd/"local_data")
os.write(os.pwd/"local_data"/"03_ssa_fruits.csv", "")
os.write(os.pwd/"local_data"/"03_ssa_can.csv", "")
os.write(os.pwd/"local_data"/"03_ssa_veg.csv", "")
os.write(os.pwd/"local_data"/"sxattru.csv", "")
os.write(os.pwd/"local_data"/"sxprod.csv", "")
os.write(os.pwd/"local_data"/"sxstore.csv", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pathStringToPath(pathString: String): Path = Paths.get(pathString)

def pathStringToDir(pathString: String): Option[File] = pathToDir(pathStringToPath(pathString))

def pathToDir(path: Path): Option[File] = {
  val file = path.toFile
  file.isDirectory match {
    case true => Some(file)
    case false => None
  }
}

def filesInDir(pathString: String): List[File] = {
  val dirOption = pathStringToDir(pathString)
  dirOption.fold(List.empty[File])(dir => dir.listFiles().toList)
}

def filesWithPrefixInDir(dirPathString: String, fileNamePrefix: String): List[File] =
  filesInDir(dirPathString).filter(file => file.getName.startsWith(fileNamePrefix))

filesWithPrefixInDir(parentDir, "03_ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fetchFilesFromLocalDirectory(path : String) : List[File] = {
        val path = Paths.get(path)

        val file = path.toFile
        if(file.isDirectory){
            file.listFiles().filter(_.getName.endsWith(".txt")).toList
        }else List[File]() // TODO: If is not a directory, it should throw an error
    }
```